# Spinner Item text is show with cut text

Tags: android, spinner

I have one spinner in which I have set the value through an `Adapter`. The problem is that  when the spinner is closed at that time it shows the text as perfectly readable with proper size. But when we click on spinner and show the text, that text shows me as not readable that means with cut text.

This problem is only occurring on Galaxy Tab and Galaxy s3. Means with screen size high. So please can anybody help me to solve this problem?

The screen shot of spinner is [image: text cut in spinner] and I want actually this
 [image: correct spinner text]

The Spinner code in xml is

```
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/ddCountry"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
/>
```

I have set the one style to set the textcolor to black, and the code is like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
   <style name="Theme.NoTitleBar.WithColoredSpinners" parent="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
        <item name="android:spinnerItemStyle">@style/SpinnerItem</item>
        <item name="android:spinnerDropDownItemStyle">@style/SpinnerItem.DropDownItem</item>
    </style>
    <style name="SpinnerItem" parent="@android:style/Widget.TextView.SpinnerItem">
        <item name="android:textColor">#000000</item>
    </style>

    <style name="SpinnerItem.DropDownItem" parent="@android:style/Widget.DropDownItem.Spinner">
        <item name="android:textColor">#000000</item>
     </style>

</resources>
```

The code for fillup the value in spinner is like this:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                Registration.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
        dataAdapter
                .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner1.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
```

This code is working in most of devices, but the problem comes when screen size is high like Galaxy Tab.

Comment: can you add the used Code for the spinner to know witch layout are you passing.

Comment: That means for pass value in spinner right?

Comment: yes, also can you explain exactly when the text is cut. I thing that the problem comes from enabling drawing cache.

Comment: i have not set any extra property for this but i have set one style for showing the text color black.Now i will post both code of style and value fillup in spinner code.

Comment: can you confirm that your are using the same layout like the following code.(android.R.layout.simple_sp...)
Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
// Create an ArrayAdapter using the string array and a default spinner layout
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
        R.array.planets_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
// Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
// Apply the adapter to the spinner
spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

Comment: Yup,because i have copy paste the current use layout.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17299/discussion-between-anis-and-nency)

Comment: Perhaps Samsung has modified the stock xml layouts.  I would try changing the dropdown layout to one of your own creation and see what happens.  Or you could add text size to your dropdown style.

Comment: i have set the textsize also but not solve the problem

Comment: have you tested the sample project ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution.Its my mistake that i had set the `android:anyDensity="false"`.So it was not working in Galaxy tab.

Answer (score 1):

try the following code:

```
      <Spinner
android:id="@+id/ddCountry"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="20dp"
 />
```

try to change the layout_height as want to fit ur spinner

Comment: i have not problem when the spinner is closd that means default text is shown properly but when click on spliner and show the list at that time i show the cut text.so if i change the spinner size then it will not solve the text size problem

Answer (score 0):

Set `android:layout_height="wrap_content"`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is obviously in your dropdown layout.

Rather than using the stock drop-down layout of `android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item` (which Samsung may have modified for their devices), create your own and set the text size to match the closed spinner.

This could be as simple as copying the default to your layout directory, changing the name and tweaking the layout itself by adding/changing the text size.

Comment: In style i have set the texisize but it will not solve the cut text problem

Comment: Then, as I mentioned above, you need to make your own dropdown layout.  That will let you control the text size and everything else about the presentation of the dropdown.